# Unknown attribute for ... on build command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to make an app with nested routes and assocciations like:

```
/char_type/:param1/char_attr/:param2
```

I used gem `nested_scaffold` to generate everything for me.

I ended up with models:

```
class CharacterType < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
    has_many :character_attribute
end

class CharacterAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :character_types
end
```

Migrations:

```
class CreateCharTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :char_types do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :avatar

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCharAttrs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
    create_table :char_attrs do |t|
      t.references :char_types, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.integer :value
      t.string :avatar

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

CharacterTypesController:

```
class CharacterTypesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_character_type, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @character_types = CharacterType.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @character_type = CharacterType.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @character_type = CharacterType.new(character_type_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @character_type.save
        format.html { redirect_to @character_type, notice: 'Character type was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @character_type }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @character_type.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @character_type.update(character_type_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @character_type, notice: 'Character type was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @character_type }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @character_type.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @character_type.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to character_types_url, notice: 'Character type was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_character_type
      @character_type = CharacterType.find(params[:id])
    end

    def character_type_params
      params.require(:character_type).permit(:name, :avatar)
    end
end
```

And CharacterAttributesController:

```
class CharacterAttributesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_character_attributes
  before_action :set_character_attribute, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @character_attributes = @character_types.character_attributes
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @character_attribute = @character_types.character_attribute.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @character_attribute = @character_types.character_attributes.build(character_attribute_params)

    if @character_attribute.save
      redirect_to([@character_attribute.character_types, @character_attribute], notice: 'Character attribute was successfully created.')
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @character_attribute.update_attributes(character_attribute_params)
      redirect_to([@character_attribute.character_types, @character_attribute], notice: 'Character attribute was successfully updated.')
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @character_attribute.destroy

    redirect_to character_types_character_attributes_url(@character_types)
  end

  private

    def set_character_attributes
      @character_types = CharacterType.find(params[:character_type_id].to_i)
    end

    def set_character_attribute
      puts("im entering here:1")
      puts("params is:1")
      puts(params[:character_type_id].inspect)
      @character_attribute = @character_types.character_attributes.find(character_types_id: params[:character_type_id].to_i)
    end

    def character_attribute_params
      params.require(:character_attribute).permit(:name, :value, :avatar)
    end
end
```

and View form for a new `char_attr`:

```
<%= form_for([@character_attribute.character_types, @character_attribute]) do |f| %>
  <% if @character_attribute.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@character_attribute.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this character_attribute from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @character_attribute.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :value %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :value %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avatar %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Where I get my error is in CharacterAttributeController when I try to create new CharacterAttribute for an existing CharacterType through the function `new`.

I call it from my view like:

```
new_character_type_character_attribute_path(character_type_id: character_type[:id])
```

And I get the error:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in CharAttrsController#new
unknown attribute 'char_type_id' for CharAttr.

 # GET char_types/1/char_attrs/new
  def new
    @char_attr = @char_types.char_attrs.build
  end

 # GET char_types/1/char_attrs/1/edit

Request
Parameters:    
{"char_type_id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Is there a form or a view from where you send the values for a new object?

Comment: Yes there is, shouldn't the 'new' function in the Controller be called first? To instantiate an empty object? Ill update the question with a view form.

Comment: Yes, I mean, in order to know where does `char_type_id` come from, could it be `character_type_id` or `character_types_id`?

Comment: `has_many :character_attribute` to `has_many :character_attributes` and `belongs_to :character_types` to `belongs_to :character_type`

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I updated the question, added the form.

Comment: why is your model name CharacterType and your table name char_types why didn't you use convection your references for some reason is plural so that will create char_types_id that is wrong I urge you to start from the begging and use rails convection don`t try to fix this because it all badly done.

Comment: @Sedad.Kosovac Naming in Rails is very confusing to me, and im not sure I could generate everything I need for nested routes described before on my own. Can you refer me some online material for nested routes?

Comment: Your problem are not routes your request goes to right controller I`m talking about your model and migration when creating model use rails genertor for example in this case rails g model CharacterAttribute value:integer character_type:references all you need to know abut rails use rails api docs and rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 1):

If you need to refer to different table you could set it using

```
class CharacterAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'char_attrs'
  belongs_to :character_type
end
```

By default rails would be looking for `character_attributes` table, which doesn't exist.

Then you could do,

```
@char_type.character_attributes.build()
```

Comment: t.references :char_types, foreign_key: true   belongs_to :character_types
also he used plural for some reason